# How to make more space space between typography and tabs in AppBar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Please find the code here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-cookies-e4w5o

Specifically

```
 <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6">News</Typography>

          <Tabs
            // variant="fullWidth"
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}
            aria-label="nav tabs example"
          >
            <LinkTab label="Page One" href="/drafts" {...a11yProps(0)} />
            <LinkTab label="Page Two" href="/trash" {...a11yProps(1)} />
            <LinkTab label="Page Three" href="/spam" {...a11yProps(2)} />
          </Tabs>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Page One
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Page Two
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Page Three
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
```

How should I make more space a space between `News` and `Page One` as follows:
[image]

Comment: What does it mean "leave space"? You want to remove the space?

Comment: @DennisVash Good catch, I want to make more space as you can see the red underline is almost touching the News

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a margin to the `Typography`:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  //...
  mx: {
    marginRight: 10
  }
}));

<Typography className={classes.mx}>News</Typography>
```